# You are running in emergency mode

Tags: boot, mountpoint

I attempted to change the name of a mount point using Disks app. After rebooting I got this message:

[image]

I don’t care about editing the mount point names. All I want is to get my HHD up and running again.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: file:///home/jc/Desktop/emergency.png

Comment: that is a local file adress. it is literally useless to anyone other than you. try to edit your question by insterting the image there. use the option "insert image" then either brose for your file or drag and drop it in the box.

Comment: We can't access a link to a local file on your computer.  Upload it somewhere- we prefer that you use [Imgur](https://imgur.com/).  Please also elaborate with the exact details of what you did to end up in your predicament.  Please use [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1271162/edit) to update your question with critical info.

Comment: Thank I will do that

Comment: I believe I uploaded the image this time

Comment: Boot with a live USB, mount the root file system and check your /etc/fstab file. Perhaps you messed up the UUIDs. Try verifying the UUIDs with 'sudo lsblk' and change accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time to try and help me. But, I gave up and reinstalled the OS.